# Playing a loop of videos by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am trying to write code to play a continous loop of two videos. I have tried to do so by this code, but it has not been done. Being new to html5 and javascript need help to make required corrections.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>

<script>

var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0]="videfirst.mp4";
videoSource[1]="videosecond.mp4";
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]); 


 function videoPlay(videoNum)
    {
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource   [videoNum]);
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
    }



    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener     ('ended',myHandler,false);
 function myHandler() {
 i++;
 if(i == (videoCount-1)){
 i = 0;
    videoPlay(i);
    }
    else{
    videoPlay(i);
    }

   }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<video controls  height="180" width="300" id="video" > 

</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `video src` should be .webm, .ogg, or .mp4 a html document is not a valid source

Comment: HI Andrew, if I am not wrong, Youtube videos are .mp4, so I have used youtube links.

Comment: you still cant expect the `<video>` element to find the source file on the html document. What do you think will happen if you had `<img src="google.com?q=lolcats">`? you won't get a picture of a funny cat that's for sure

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks a lot for clearing my concept. But here the code is not doing with .mp4 videos. I just thought YouTube videos to be more relevant, but lot of thanks you have cleared my concept. Now I am going to put .mp4 videos in the code so that the persons like you may go further to help me without pondering at my silly mistake.